# php- Google AppEngine TaskQueues not working

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am using PHP 5.5 and want to use Google AppEngine TaskQueues for async. task processing. My code is:

```
<?php

require_once 'google/appengine/api/taskqueue/PushTask.php';
use googleappengineapitaskqueuePushTask;
$task = new PushTask('/sendBulk.php', ['msg' => $msgtext, 'phone' => $targets]);
$task_name = $task->add();

?>
```

But I am getting this error:

*Fatal error: Class 'PushTask' not found in file.php on line 5*

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it's how you've pasted in your code snippet, but the namespace is wrong (mising backslashes). Also, you don't need the require_once any more.

So your code should look something like,

```
use \google\appengine\api\taskqueue\PushTask;

$task = new PushTask('/push_handler.php', [], ['delay_seconds' => 5.0]);
$task_name = $task->add();
```

Comment: I guess I have tried it already. Still I tried again but the same error:
    
    Fatal error: Class 'google \appengine\api\taskqueue \PushTask' not found in file.php.

I get this where I use '$task = new PushTask( ... )'.

Comment: My GAE directory structure is as: google/appengine/api/taskqueue/PushTask.php